# How do I remove part of a line in a multi-line chunk using sed or Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, sed

I have some data that looks like this. It comes in chunk of four. Each chunk starts with a `@` character.

```
@SRR037212.1 FC30L5TAA_102708:7:1:741:1355 length=27
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+SRR037212.1 FC30L5TAA_102708:7:1:741:1355 length=27
::::::::::::::::::::::::;;8
@SRR037212.2 FC30L5TAA_102708:7:1:1045:1765 length=27
TATAACCAGAAAGTTACAAGTAAACAC
+SRR037212.2 FC30L5TAA_102708:7:1:1045:1765 length=27
888888888888888888888888888
```

At the third line of each chunk, I want to remove the text that comes after the `+` character, resulting in:

```
@SRR037212.1 FC30L5TAA_102708:7:1:741:1355 length=27
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+
::::::::::::::::::::::::;;8
@SRR037212.2 FC30L5TAA_102708:7:1:1045:1765 length=27
TATAACCAGAAAGTTACAAGTAAACAC
+
888888888888888888888888888
```

Is there a compact way to do that in sed or Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is never a + on the first or second lines and always one on the third line:

```
perl -0100pi -e's/\+.*/+/' datafile
```

Otherwise:

```
perl -0100pi -e's/^((?:.*\n){2}.*?\+).*/$1/' datafile
```

or on 5.10+:

```
perl -0100pi -e's/^(?:.*\n){2}.*?\+\K.*//' datafile
```

All those assume @ only appears at the start of a chunk.  If it may appear other places, then:

```
perl -pi -e's/\+.*/+/ if $. % 4 == 3' datafile
```

Comment: I believe this blindly removes every line starting with a `+`. If so, I'm fairly sure the OP wants it to be keyed on the 4-line chunk starting with a `@`

Comment: Fourth line of each chunk ma start with +.

Comment: @SiegeX: the -0100 makes it read @-separated chunks (chr(0100) is '@')

Comment: I tried all your code but doesn't print any output. Your last one is the one suits for my purpose.

Comment: @neversaint: The -i flag tells it to modify the file instead of printing; if you'd rather print, leave it off.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you just don't want to blindly remove the rest of *every* line starting with a `+`, then you can do this:

```
sed '/^@/{N;N;s/\n+.*/\n+/}' infile
```

#### Output

```
$ sed '/^@/{N;N;s/\n+.*/\n+/}' infile
@SRR037212.1 FC30L5TAA_102708:7:1:741:1355 length=27
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+
::::::::::::::::::::::::;;8
@SRR037212.2 FC30L5TAA_102708:7:1:1045:1765 length=27
TATAACCAGAAAGTTACAAGTAAACAC
+
888888888888888888888888888
+Dont remove me
```

*Note: Although the above command keys on the `@` to determine if a line with a `+` should be altered, it *will* still alter the 2nd line if it happens to also start with a `+`. It doesn't sound like this is the case, but if you want to exclude this corner case as well, the following minor alteration will protect against that:

```
sed '/^@/{N;N;s/\(.*\)\n+.*/\1\n+/}' infile
```

#### Output

```
$ sed '/^@/{N;N;s/\(.*\)\n+.*/\1\n+/}' ./infile
@SRR037212.1 FC30L5TAA_102708:7:1:741:1355 length=27
+AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+
::::::::::::::::::::::::;;8
@SRR037212.2 FC30L5TAA_102708:7:1:1045:1765 length=27
TATAACCAGAAAGTTACAAGTAAACAC
+
888888888888888888888888888
+Dont remove me
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the 4th line may start with @ also. Seems that your code will skip that chunk.

Comment: @neversaint Is that a guess or did you test it against input upon which my code didn't work?  If it's the latter, could you please update your question with the input that is not working and also revise your requirement as it currently states these batches come in 4-line chunks which doesn't seem to be truly accurate according to your previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use awk, you can do:

```
 gawk '{if ($0 ~ /^@/ ) { print ; getline ; print ; getline ; print "+"}}' INPUTFILE
```

So if gawk sees an `@` at the start of the line, it will be printed, then the next line will be slurped && printed, and finally slurping the 3rd line (after the `@`), and printing only the `+`.

If the `+` is not on the start of the line, you can use `gensub(/\+.*/,"+",$0)` instead of the `"+"` in the last `print`.

(And if you have `perl` installed, most probably there will be an `a2p` executable, which can convert the above awk script to perl, if you want to...)

HTH

**UPDATE** (on missing 4th line):

```
 gawk '{if ($0 ~ /^@/ ) { print ; getline ; print ; getline ; print "+"; getline; print }}' INPUTFILE
```

This should print the 4th line as well.

Comment: Thanks Botykai, but our code skip printing the 4th line of each chunk.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just `sed '/^@/+2 s/+.*/+/'`

**edit**: this will not work, but as a vim command it should work:

```
vim file -c ':g/^@/+2s/+.*/+/' -c 'wq'
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gave me this message sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown command: `+

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^@/{$!N;$!N;$!N;s/\n+[^\n]*/\n+/g}' file
```

or with GNU sed:

```
sed '/^@/,+3s/^+.*/+/' file
```